# Windows Server 2016 Datacenter or Windows 10 for .NET web development

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, virtual-machine, development-environment

Usually I select Windows Server 2016 Datacenter when provisioning a new VM in Azure for .NET web development.

IIS, Visual Studio are basically the minimum requirements.

It struck me today, why am I not using Windows 10 instead?

What are the main reasons to use one over the other?

Comment: It's hard to say which one is better for your scenario. **It really depends on your requirement**. Usually, for development, Windows server is more feature than Windows Client.  But sometimes , Windows10 also have some features that Sever doesn't have. Just choose the right one for your OS.

Answer (score -1):

[Differences between server and desktop OS](https://www.quadricsoftware.com/2016/01/29/4-key-differences-between-a-windows-server-and-a-windows-desktop-installation/)

1. Windows Server Supports More Memory
2. Windows Server Uses CPUs More Efficiently
3. More Network Connections Allowed on a Windows Server
4. The Server OS is Configured for Background Tasks

[Windows 2016 wins in desktop virtualization](https://www.ivanti.com/blog/windows-10-windows-server-2016-old-battle-vdi-versus-rdsh/)

Comment: can you elaborate the issue what is going on from your end at that moment only we can suggest anything from our end.